# How can I determine the object type of sender's Parent.Parent in an event?

Tags: c#

I have an event called AvailableDeckTapped that can be sent from an object with a CollectionView or a TreeView as its Parent.Parent:

```
    private void AvailableDeckTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var availableDeck = sender as AvailableDeckTemplate;
        var availableDeckCollectionView = availableDeck.Parent.Parent as CollectionView;

    private void AvailableDeckTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var availableDeck = sender as AvailableDeckTemplate;
        var availableDeckTreeView = availableDeck.Parent.Parent as TreeView;
```

Is there a way I can find out what the type of the Parent.Parent is so that I can execute different code depending on the type?

I'm looking for the ability to do something like this:

```
    if (available.Parent.Parent.Type == CollectionView) 
    {
    }
```

But I assume `available.Parent.Parent.Type` is not the way to do this.

Comment: Erm, use the `typeof` operator or call `GetType()` ???

Comment: Well you can use `if (available.Parent.Parent is CollectionView collectionView) { /* use collectionView here */ }`

Comment: `x as T` yields `null` if the type of `x` is not assignable to `T` so that is one way you can control the flow. However, the idiomatic approach would be to use a type pattern `if (availableDeck.Parent.Parent is Collection View availableDeckCollectionView) { do something with availableDeckCollectionView }`